# Bitboard based array generation problems in Java

Tags: java, arrays, bit-manipulation

I am making an advanced chess engine for fun. I would like to use bit boards to monitor the positions of my pieces, however, the thing isn't working. I have written the method to convert a string of binary digits into the numerical representation so it can be stored in a long. I have verified that that part of the program works. My problem is with the to array method, which returns an array missing a rook instead of a filled array.

This is the result I expect when I call the method:

```
[ r, n, b, q, k, b, n, r]
[ p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p]
[  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[ P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P]
[ R, N, B, Q, K, B, N, R]
```

This is what I get:

```
[r, n, b, q, k, b, n, r]
[p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p]
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P]
[ , N, B, Q, K, B, N, R]
```

Here is the source code of the chess class:

```
package chess2;
import com.google.common.base.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Chess {
    private static long WR = 0L;
    private static long WN = 0L;
    private static long WB = 0L;
    private static long WQ = 0L;
    private static long WK = 0L;
    private static long WP = 0L;
    private static long BR = 0L;
    private static long BN = 0L;
    private static long BB = 0L;
    private static long BQ = 0L;
    private static long BK = 0L;
    private static long BP = 0L;
    private static double time;
    private static Scanner read;
    //private static long EP = 0L;

    public Chess(int id) {
        String wR = "1000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        String wN = "0100001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        String wB = "0010010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        String wQ = "0000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        String wK = "0001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        String wP = "0000000011111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        String bR = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000001";
        String bN = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000010";
        String bB = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100100";
        String bQ = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000";
        String bK = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000";
        String bP = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111100000000";
        String time1 = stringToLong(wR, wN, wB, wQ, wK, wP, bR, bN, bB, bK, bQ, bP);
        read = new Scanner(time1);
        time = read.nextDouble();
    }

    public static String stringToLong(String wR2, String wN2, String wB2,
            String wQ2, String wK2, String wP2, String bR2, String bN2,
            String bB2, String bK2, String bQ2, String bP2) {
        Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.createUnstarted();
        timer.start();
        WR = stringToLong(wR2);
        WN = stringToLong(wN2);
        WB = stringToLong(wB2);
        WQ = stringToLong(wQ2);
        WK = stringToLong(wK2);
        WP = stringToLong(wP2);
        BR = stringToLong(bR2);
        BN = stringToLong(bN2);
        BB = stringToLong(bB2);
        BQ = stringToLong(bQ2);
        BK = stringToLong(bK2);
        BP = stringToLong(bP2);
        String time = timer.stop().toString();
        return time;
    }

    public static long stringToLong(String Binary) {
        if (Binary.charAt(0) =='0') { //not going to be a negative number
            return Long.parseLong(Binary, 2);
        } 
        else { //is negative
            return Long.parseLong("1" + Binary.substring(2), 2) * 2;
        }
    }

    public double getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ("" + WR + " \n" + WN + " \n" + WB + " \n" + WQ + " \n" + WK + " \n" + WP + " \n"+
                   + BR + " \n" + BN + " \n" + BB + " \n" + BQ + " \n" + BK + " \n" + BP + " \n");
    }

    public String[][] toArray() {
        String chessBoard[][] = new String[8][8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            chessBoard[i / 8][i % 8] = " ";
        }
        for (int i=0;i<64;i++) {
            if (((WP >> i) & 1) == 1) {
                chessBoard[i/8][i%8]="P";
            }
            else if (((WN >> i) & 1) == 1) {
                chessBoard[i/8][i%8]="N";
            }
            else if (((WB >> i) & 1) == 1) {
                chessBoard[i/8][i%8]="B";
            }
            else if (((WR >> i) & 1) == 1) {
                chessBoard[i/8][i%8]="R";
            }
            else if (((WQ >> i) & 1) == 1) {
                chessBoard[i/8][i%8]="Q";
            }
            else if (((WK >> i) & 1) == 1) {
                chessBoard[i/8][i%8]="K";
            }
            else if (((BP >> i) & 1) == 1) {
                chessBoard[i/8][i%8]="p";
            }
            else if (((BN >> i) & 1) == 1) {
                chessBoard[i/8][i%8]="n";
            }
            else if (((BB >> i) & 1) == 1) {
                chessBoard[i/8][i%8]="b";
            }
            else if (((BR >> i) & 1) == 1) {
                chessBoard[i/8][i%8]="r";
            }
            else if (((BQ >> i) & 1) == 1) {
                chessBoard[i/8][i%8]="q";
            }
            else if (((BK >> i) & 1) == 1) {
                chessBoard[i/8][i%8]="k";
            }
        }
        return chessBoard;
    }
}
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT*

Sorry, I put the wrong code!

Comment: Don't declare chessBoard as a local variable?

Comment: @Gosu ,How else should I do it? The `chessBoard` in `toArray()` is completely different from the `chessBoard` in `initiateStandardChess()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass in all your `long` variables like `WP`, `WN`, `WB` etc to your `arrayToBitboards` function, because if you do then the values you set inside the function will just be the parameter variables and not the member variables in the class.

```
public static void arrayToBitboards(String[][] chessBoard) {
    ...
}
```

call:

```
arrayToBitboards(chessBoard);
```